# Accessing data from ORM in pug

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, pug

I have a question, when I pass an Instance to the Pug file I just access the object passed as

```
 each row in headings
  tr
   td= row.id
```

while the objects is wrapped under an object itself, so how I am able to access the id just **row.id** and I am getting the same result with **row.dataValues.id**

```
Book {
    dataValues: {
      id: 10,
      title: 'Frankenstein',
      author: 'Mary Shelley',
      genre: 'Horror',
      year: 1818,
      createdAt: Invalid Date,
      updatedAt: Invalid Date
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 10,
      title: 'Frankenstein',
      author: 'Mary Shelley',
      genre: 'Horror',
      year: 1818,
      createdAt: Invalid Date,
      updatedAt: Invalid Date
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get({ plain: true})` method on a model instance to get a plain object.

```js
const book = await Books.findOne({
  // options
})
const plainBook = book.get({ plain: true})
```

Comment: Thankyou sir for replying, but actually the question is that sir without getting the plain object, it is still working, what can be the reason @Anatoly

Comment: Yes, you can use `book.id` (it would just a getter to get a value from `dataValues`). I meant if you need to pass the whole object it's better to have a plain object instead of Sequelize model instance with special getters, method and so on